# What is this circular icon in my Android status bar?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

I'm getting the circular symbol to the right of K/s on my status bar since last few days:

[image]

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **GPS in use** icon

From [MI forums](https://kknews.cc/digital/6n6lemq.html) translated using Google

> This icon indicates that the phone is using the GPS signal, and if you are using the phone navigation it is not wrong. Otherwise it is recommended as soon as possible to close the power consumption, so that mobile phone power consumption too fast.

Someone who can read original can point out errors .

**Edit** From [Mi Forums](http://en.miui.com/thread-622527-1-1.html) in English

> Google's locator icon, which uses wifi, cell and GPS to locate you. To turn off, go to settings>Google>location> untick Access to my location.
>
> It appears when one or more apps [you gave permission to] is asking for your location, hence your phone is transmitting.

OP has provided additional information on getting rid of the icon, which may help others

> What solved for me was that Go to Settings > Additional Settings > Privacy > Location > Location access. Then in app permissions for each app I disabled Location. Then restarted the phone. The icon was now gone. Then enabled the location for all apps that previously had it enabled

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make it disappear?

Comment: Thanks! What solved for me was that Go to Settings > Additional Settings > Privacy > Location > Location access. Then in app permissions for each app I disabled Location. Then restarted the phone. The icon was now gone. Then enabled the location for all apps that previously had it enabled. You can add this to your answer and I'll accept it. Add a comment once you edit your answer